# MySQL join performance issue with OR condition

Tags: mysql

Can anyone think of a more efficient way to write this query as it keeps timing out when I run it?

```
SELECT 
orders.OrderKey,
shipout.primary_subcategory
FROM
orders
    INNER JOIN
orderitems ON orderitems.OrderID = orders.OrderID
    INNER JOIN
subjects ON subjects.SubjectID = orderitems.SubjectID
    INNER JOIN
subjectdetails ON subjectdetails.SubjectID = subjects.SubjectID
    INNER JOIN
shipout ON shipout.id_invoice = subjects.SubjectKey
        OR shipout.id_invoice = orders.OrderKey
GROUP BY orders.orderkey
```

If I remove the OR condition, it finishes in .2 seconds. And even if I switch the last join with the orders table instead of the subjects table, it finishes in .1 seconds.

```
shipout ON shipout.id_invoice = orders.OrderKey
GROUP BY orders.orderkey
```

But when I try to join both at the same time with OR it times out. Here's the explain:

```
+----+-------------+----------------+--------+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+--------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type |     table      |  type  |              possible_keys              |         key          | key_len |           ref            |  rows  |                       Extra                        |
+----+-------------+----------------+--------+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+--------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | shipout        | ALL    |                                         |                      |         |                          |  10658 | Using temporary; Using filesort                    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | subjectdetails | index  | PRIMARY                                 | SubjectDetails_ID    |     768 |                          | 455446 | Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | subjects       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,Subjects_SubjectKey             | PRIMARY              |       4 | subjectdetails.SubjectID |      1 |                                                    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | orderitems     | ref    | OrderItems_OrderID,OrderItems_SubjectID | OrderItems_SubjectID |       5 | subjectdetails.SubjectID |      1 |                                                    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | orders         | eq_ref | PRIMARY,Orders_OrderKey                 | PRIMARY              |       4 | orderitems.OrderID       |      1 | Using where                                        |
+----+-------------+----------------+--------+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+--------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

One thing to note is, I'm not the database admin, so I can't index tables. It looks like subjectdetails is, but I'm not sure about shipout.

Comment: "One thing to note is, I'm not the database admin, so I can't index tables" Ask the database admin for advice and indexing.. Seeing "Using temporary; Using filesort " and "Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)" in the explain is bad news and requires indexing for sure.. Most likely rewritting the OR statement into a UNION kind of query also might improve preformance with correct indexing.

Comment: Why do you need subjectdetails? It does not seem to be used?

Comment: @ewramner you're right it doesn't for this query. I had some columns selected from that table in a previous query, but forgot to remove the join when I removed the selected. Either way though, I run into the same problem with the join removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A UNION rewrite of your current query. 
Might also gain performance with correct indexing.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
orders.OrderKey,
shipout.primary_subcategory
FROM
orders
    INNER JOIN
orderitems ON orderitems.OrderID = orders.OrderID
    INNER JOIN
subjects ON subjects.SubjectID = orderitems.SubjectID
    INNER JOIN
subjectdetails ON subjectdetails.SubjectID = subjects.SubjectID
    INNER JOIN
shipout ON shipout.id_invoice = subjects.SubjectKey
GROUP BY orders.orderkey

UNION ALL

SELECT 
orders.OrderKey,
shipout.primary_subcategory
FROM
orders
    INNER JOIN
orderitems ON orderitems.OrderID = orders.OrderID
    INNER JOIN
subjects ON subjects.SubjectID = orderitems.SubjectID
    INNER JOIN
subjectdetails ON subjectdetails.SubjectID = subjects.SubjectID
    INNER JOIN
shipout ON shipout.id_invoice = orders.OrderKey
GROUP BY orders.orderkey
```

> One thing to note is, I'm not the database admin, so I can't index
>   tables

**But still ask the database admin for advice and indexing.**

Comment: Great suggestion. I'll have to remember the Union operator for the future. This worked great and queried in .4 seconds.

Comment: This trick only makes sense when you are using two separted (indexes) columns like `WHERE column1 = 1 OR column2 = 1` that can be rewritten into a `UNION ALL` approach. @Brandon `WHERE column1 = 1 OR column1 = 2` would not really make sense to rewite in a `UNION ALL` `WHERE column1 = 1 OR column1 = 2` a rewrite to `WHERE column IN(1, 2)` would make more sense.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the further explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to rewrite the last JOIN like this:

```
shipout ON shipout.id_invoice = COALESCE(subjects.SubjectKey, orders.OrderKey)
```

Like this the OR is eliminated, but the same rows are joined. This only works if the subjects.SubjectKey / orders.OrderKey is NULL if the other isn't when the JOIN is made, but it's hard to tell without knowing your exact data structure.

Comment: Using COALESCE is not a great idea because it stops MySQL from using a index on subjects.SubjectKey or orders.OrderKey

Comment: Good point, if the query runs within miliseconds without the OR this could still solve the problem though. Had a very similar performance issue which was solved by this recently.

Comment: I like this idea and could see its application, but yeah, it doesn't work for my specific data set